# I am creating Cucumber Project with JTDS which is like JDBC. No current row in the ResultSet

Tags: java, cucumber, jtds

I want to use the one row from resultset as input to another query.

I was trying to print the only one row from the resultset and I am unable to do it.

The code I am using is

```
System.out.println(arg2);
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd1 = rs1.getMetaData();
        String column = rsmd1.getColumnName(1);
        System.out.println(column);
        int Count = rsmd1.getColumnCount();
        System.out.println(Count);
        String Output1 = rs1.getString(arg2);
        System.out.println(Output1);

        while (rs1.next()){
        for (int i = 1; i <= Count ; i++){
            String Output = rs1.getString(arg2);
            System.out.println(Output + " ");
        }System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.println("Select * from "+ arg1+" where "+ arg2 + " in (");
        throw new PendingException();
            }
```

and output I am getting at console

```
Appl_No
Appl_No
200
```

Comment: For a start `String Output = rs1.getString(arg2);` `Output` is limited in scope to the `while` loop, so you can not use it outside of the loop.  Also if you only want the first result, then why even do a while, why not `if`?

Comment: jTDS isn't "like" JDBC, it **is** a JDBC implementation (and a lot better than the official MS driver).

Comment: well @ScaryWombat I have used the String Output and Output1. I want to print to console the first row which is Appl_No. I am getting that as ColumnName from rsmd1. But when i am using the rs.next method i am unable to print.

Comment: If `rs1.next()` returns `false`, there are no (more) rows. First make sure you actually have rows in the resultset.

Comment: @Kayaman I was also skeptical about the same issue and that is the reason I have used resultmetadata and printed the ColumnName for 1 column and it has the ColumnName which i was giving later which is Appl_No

Comment: I'm not talking about columns, I'm talking about rows. You printing out column names doesn't tell you anything about whether there are rows or not. If you write `if(!rs1.next()) System.out.println("No rows");` you can see if you have rows or not. Your metadata code is completely useless.

Comment: @Kayaman where should i write the code you have given to me as i tried it before the while loop as well as in the loop as well. But both the times its not giving me any result.

Comment: Well, try `if(rs1.next()) System.out.println("We have rows!");` instead.

Comment: @Kayaman still no result

Comment: Well, `rs1.next()` returns a `boolean` which as we know is either `true` or `false`. The code snippets I gave you test for both. Saying neither prints out anything isn't something I believe. Keep trying, it's up to you now.